# Does the OP get notified of new answers for migrated questions?

Tags: support, questions, migration, migrated-questions

Particularly, if they don't yet have an account on the migrated site, do they still get notified of new answers for their question? (eg. via inbox or email)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sometime ago, I honestly don't recall exactly when, we changed this behavior.

Users will be notified of comments and answers on their migrated posts via new items in their global inbox.