# When questions get migrated, encourage OP to register on target site

Tags: feature-request, migrated-questions

<sup>(Pro-tip: skip to the **bolded** part if this is *tl;dr* for you)</sup>

Stack Overflow was (and still is) the site I'm currently the most engaged and involved on in terms of reviewing, editing and flagging questions and answers, as well as posting my own answers. However, the first time a question I answered got migrated (to Pro Webmasters), I registered an account on there as well to not only follow the question, but to amend it should the OP follow suit (by registering an account), or have follow-up comments.

Regrettably, so many new users and even some semi-established ones, just don't bother registering on the site their question has been migrated to and I think this is a real shame. Particularly for Pro Webmasters, which I think has some really great potential for massive growth, is awesome in its own right and deserves way more traffic which could result from the questions and answers that it could get if more people registered due to their questions being migrated. As it stands now, a lot of the [answers to migrated questions](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/24211/is-su-pr-no-longer-supported/24213)<sup>*</sup> just never get *marked as the answer* either, due to this issue.

Since the OP [doesn't get notified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111730/does-the-op-get-notified-of-new-answers-for-migrated-questions) about new answers on a migrated question until they've registered an account on the site their question was migrated to either, and the message they're greeted with upon migration itself is very perfunctory in just stating "your question has been migrated" with a link to where it was migrated to, **I'd like to make a `feature-request` that there's a little more prodding and cajoling for the OP to register an account on the site their question was migrated to**. Ideas on how to do this if you agree with me, would be very welcome.

<sup>*Disclosure: I used one of my answers on a migrated question as an example.</sup>

<sup>**I failed at finding suitable synonyms for *migrate* in the intended context, so apologies for repeating the word *ad nauseam* above.</sup>

Comment: Note, the OP is already notified on comments and new answers **regardless** of whether they have an account or not. I am not sure what more we can do.

Comment: see linked question, the answer from Anna is out of date

Comment: Well dang it, @waffles, post that as an answer so I can accept it. It has been two years already... ;-P