# Clarification of the question after a migration

Tags: discussion, migration, migrated-questions, migration-rejection

So a question is migrated from one site to another.  Not something thats terribly uncommon.

But now, you've got a question from a non-user that needs clarification.  Comments on the question go nowhere.  All the OP knows is that the question was migrated to another site.

Its not a bad question (the 'don't migrate crap' rule), but it *does* need additional work using clarifications form the target community before it can become an answerable question - there are issues that threaten it to be closed as unclear.

So, how do you get the feedback to the OP on the original site that he or she needs to go to the new site, create an account, and answer the questions?

The *only* thing I can really think of at this time is to flag the question on the origin site to persuade a mod to leave a comment on the closed/locked question for the OP to go to the target site and participate there.  (Yes, I *could* leave a comment on another question *if* one exists, but thats a bit of abuse of comments that really isn't the right approach)

Is there another way? Does there need to be some 'comment forwarding?' from the target site back to the origin site to get the comments back in the inbox?

The other approach is to try to do a heroic edit to modify the question into something appropriate for that site, *if* someone can get at the heart of the question or a related question.  The challenge there is that few people are so inclined to rework a question - and the reworking needs to be done promptly (before the migration gets rejected).  I'm fairly sure that most here are aware of the difficulty in gathering sufficient community involvement to do such heroic efforts - and the nature of the heroic edits require heroes which aren't that common.

---

Key question(s):

- Should I go and flag the original question to get a mod to prod the OP into participating?
- Are heroic edits warranted?
- Is there a feature request that should be better thought out for getting the OP to participate in the target site's migrated question?

Comment: If the post requires a heroic edit to be answerable, then it's not a high quality post, and probably shouldn't be migrated.

Comment: Users are already notified about migrations, aren't they? I suppose it would be a good thing if comments on migrated questions created an inbox notification even if the poster wasn't registered on the target site, though, if that's not already the case.

Comment: @Servy its heroic in the content of the site, but not a "bad question that will get 90% of it changed to be on topic" - it might be 10-25% with clarifications.  Though maybe my threshold for heroism is a bit lower.  There's a question, but its not clear what design patterns are being used, what languages are there or at the disposal, what the OP thinks some quote means in the context.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen they are notified "your question has been migrated to {other site}"  But thats the *only* notification they get unless they have an account on the target site too.

Comment: @MichaelT In my eyes, if the question should be closed as it stands, it shouldn't be migrated.  If it's good enough to stay open, even if it needs a bit of editing to really shine, then migrating is a useful tool.

Comment: @Servy example question that made me think of this - [P.SE: Plain old struct vs class in this case?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/221534/plain-old-struct-vs-class-in-this-case) -- it needs work on P.SE to be answerable.  The context of the quote for example, or the data structures that the OP is working with.  The alternative is for *every* moderator to be completely familiar with the requirements for all the target sites.  For some of them, that is a very nuanced area.

Comment: @MichaelT Well, 100% migration success rates, while nice, are not to b expected.  If that question can't be answered as is, close it.  Some migrations do fail.  If there is a problem with excessive bad migrations the moderators know how to deal with that, whether that means reading up on the scope of a frequent migration target (which should be done for migrating from SO to P.SE) or consulting with a mod of the target site for handling migrations.

Comment: @Servy the thing is, if it fails because the OP isn't notified if comments on the target site (which, IIRC don't show up when the migration fails back to the origin site)... is there some additional part of the process that can be improved - be it manual or automatic? We do want to provide the best user experience to the extent that it doesn't damage the site... being told "ask over here" and then "they didn't want it for unknown reasons (notifications that didn't show up)" isn't a good experience.  This *can* be fixed... somehow.

Comment: @MichaelT If a question cannot be answered until clarifying questions are answered then you shouldn't be waiting a while before closing the question; it should be closed immediately, and reopened if/when it is sufficiently clarified.  The problem in a case like this would be that the question is migrated when it shouldn't have been, not so much that it's being handled inappropriately post migration.  The moderators shouldn't be migrating questions that aren't sufficiently clear.

Comment: Ps. To answer the implied question in my earlier comment, it seems that [users _do_ get notified about comments to migrated questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111730/does-the-op-get-notified-of-new-answers-for-migrated-questions) even if they don't have an account on the target site. At least, I assume it still works that way with the new top bar.