# Are users notified when their question is migrated to a site they're not a member of?

Tags: discussion, migrated-questions

If a user asks a question on *Site A* where they're a member, and their question is migrated to *Site B* where they're not a member, will they get the migration notification?

Comment: Users are always notified on migration of their posts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that hasn't changed since the new notification bar, yes; I had an answer (on a migrated question) migrated to DBA and wasn't a member there, and was notified.

Comment: Note, you also get [notifications of comments/answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111730/does-the-op-get-notified-of-new-answers-for-migrated-questions) in your migrated posts as of (at least) early 2012.

Comment: Ok thanks. Was a question migrated to MSO recently and I saw the questioner was not a member here. Just wondered if they'd see it, as if not would have been bad. Cheers