# When a question is migrated to another site, are askers/answers who aren't members of the target site notified of later comments/answers?

Tags: support, comments, notifications, migration

I came across a question that had recently been migrated from another site, after which an experienced user added a standard asking-for-more-information comment. But I then noticed that the question's OP wasn't a user on the target site (their name was greyed out). It made me wonder if the commenter wasn't shouting into the wind.

When a question is migrated to another site, are askers/answers who aren't members of the target site notified of later comments/answers?

The question [Are users notified when their question is migrated to a site they're not a member of?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212495) asks if the users get notified of the migration, but there is seemingly nothing about what happens afterwards.

Comment: Admittedly, they might have been shouting into the wind _anyway_, regardless of notification....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, they are not; notifications caused by actions on site X are only sent to users of said site.

I don't think that this is a problem; users *are* notified that their post got migrated, and upon clicking that link, they will see the new comments/answers. So there is no need for additional notifications. If they visit the link but decide not to sign up, that's their own choice and no need for additional notifications either.